# Is there any difference between heteroscedasticity and homoscedasticity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity

It seems these terms are confusing. Some experts think that these terms have a contrasting meaning which is incorrect. Is there someone who can justify the interpretation.

Comment: They are opposites.

Comment: Homoscedasticity term is used to represent dispersion in continuous data. The term heteroscedasticity measures dispersion of binomial-effects (here in terms of extent of skewness) e.g. treatment of patient results in success i.e. 1 or failure I.e. 0.  I have stated in my answer 0, 1 type of data. In case of meta-analysis, we have data of this type and proceed with moderated regression using one or more possible moderator variables as independent variables. thanks for comment.

Comment: I don't buy your explanation. "Homo" means the same or similar . "hetero" means diverse..

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. I agree with you (upvote). Howevever, I disagree with the classfication - opposites.

Comment: My rework tells me that we can not or should not use linear regression. We can simply invoke GLM  in case of homoscedastic data  with a minor change in GlM model i.e. mulltiply the term reflecting beta(X) by p-correlation. I shall change the answer.

Comment: The experts are correct and there is no confusion at all.

Comment: These terms are not contrasts in meaning. The homoscedasticity measures dispersion first and then checks for equality or inequality of dispersion among several groups. Heterocedasticity measure  computes dispersion/skewness for groups. Each measure finally tells  how many groups are similar (and how many are dissimilar). Thus, Heterogeity shows no. of groups that hetero - disimilar and remaining are similar). The intensity of heterogeneous  reflects heterogeneity.

Answer (score 12):

They are opposites. *skedasis* means “dispersion”, so *hetero* mean different variances and *homo* indicates same/constant variances of the distribution where the shocks/errors/disturbances come from.

For example, if some observations get their errors from the blue distribution (lower variance), while others are drawn from the red (higher variance), you have heteroskedasticity.

[image]

Comment: Is there any distinction between dispersion and skewness ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar Skew is about the asymmetry of the distribution about the mean, variance is about dispersion around the mean. For a unimodal distribution, negative skew means there is a long tail is on the left side of the distribution, and positive skew indicates that the long tail is on the right.

Comment: @dimitriy-v-masterov Sir, your interpretation of skedasis is incorrect. Please recheck it.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar See [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ske%2Fdasis&la=greek&can=ske%2Fdasis0). As any thesaurus will tell you, scattering and dispersion are synonyms. If you continue to maintain that your interpretation is correct, please link or cite some authority on the matter that supports your view. Acting like Humpty Dumpty will not help in this instance.

Comment: Define scedastic
2. (Statistics) (of a bivariate or multivariate distribution) having one variable whose variance is the same for all values of the other or others. 3. (Statistics) (of a random variable) having this property.
Homoscedastic - definition of hom…
www.thefreedictionary.com/homoscedastic

Comment: "whose variance is the same for all values of the other or others." Is it sufficient to support my viewpoint ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I don't see anything at that link that contradicts what I wrote, and I have nothing more to add to the discussion here. Best of luck!

Comment: The link above clearly points out  the property - Homoscedastic if  you have two or more explainatory variables and one of the two is scedastic.

Comment: I would add that there is no need to specify errors, shocks or disturbances. Two or more distributions are homoscedastic if they have the same variance and heteroscedastic otherwise. It's likely true that errors in regresssion-type models provide the most common context for using these terms, but in principle they apply generally.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar To what has been said to you many times, I add just two further points. I can't see any _useful_ meaning at all to the word "scedastic" without prefix. If it means anything it just means variable, which is useless, because the word variable is already in use and simpler for most people not Greek.  Also homo- or heteroscedasticity has nothing whatsoever to do with skewness. If you can cite literature that says so, that would be a public service, as you would be flagging a paper or textbook to avoid.

Comment: esteemed , Mr. Nick please go through comments carefully  and you will be able to trace the source that tellls meaning of scedastic. For the meaning, you may read two comments under Dimitriy V. Masterov.. I shall explain homo and hetero in a specific context. I can not disclose everrthing.

Comment: Subhash, you had to look hard for an inferior definition of "homoscedastic" and even then you chose to cite the least relevant of the definitions offered.  Using selective quotations from unauthoritative sources to confront people (who are trying to help you out of your confusion) and to call them wrong is likely to offend anybody. Even when people are not affronted by your attitude, I'm sure they will learn not to answer any more questions you might post.

Comment: Any good English dictionary explains that _homo_ and _hetero_ are standard Greek roots, from words meaning the same or different respectively. They are in use for many words more common than homoscedastic or heteroscedastic. The thread https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153526/why-are-there-two-spellings-of-heteroskedastic-or-heteroscedastic comments on their origin and use in statistics. I doubt that I can add anything else that will be helpful. There are many problematic terms in statistics, but these aren't among them: the definitions are agreed and simple.

Answer (score -2):

They are actually opposite!

Think, for instance, of a linear model where $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is constant. Here you have homoskedasticity, since variance will always be the same, regardless of $x$

If $\epsilon$ depended on the values of $x$, you would have heteroskedasticity, with the variance being different depending on the value of the regressor

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. If the epsilons come from distributions with different *variances*, you have heteroskedasticity. This does not require dependence on $x$ (though that is common) and epsilon is definitely not constant. It is a random variable, with varying or constant variance.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Right. Your point about the variance of $\epsilon$ is especially apt.  David I think means that the variance of the distribution of $\epsilon$ is constant *a la* $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\epsilon})$, where $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ is some constant value.

Comment: I was just giving an example. You can have heteroskedascity in many different situations, not even necessarely in linear regression

Comment: You probably mean that the variance of e is constant, not e itself.